# How do I pass an object to the CreateThread function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to pass an object of a class as argument to the `CreateThread` function.

The object is created this way in `main`:

```
Connection *connection = new Bluetooth();
Brick *nxt = new Brick(connection);
```

The function that I pass to `CreateThread` is:

```
DWORD WINAPI recieveFunct(Brick nxt)
```

Finally, `CreateThread` is called in `main`:

```
IDRecieveThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, recieveFunct, *nxt, 0, NULL);
```

In `main` I create the `nxt` object. This object has read and write functions that I want to call from the thread. However, I can't get it to work.

Do I need it to cast the object to `HANDLE`? Or am I looking completely wrong?

---

Thanks for your feedback guys!

I have implemented the solution given above like this:

```
int main()
{
  HANDLE IDRecieveThread = 0;

  //set up the NXT
 Connection *connection = new Bluetooth(); Brick *nxt = new Brick(connection);


  //Setup connection
  cout << "connecting..." << endl;
  connection->connect(3);
  cout << "connected" << endl;

  cout << "Starting recieve thread...." << endl;
  IDRecieveThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, recieveFunct, reinterpret_cast<void*>(nxt),  0, NULL);
  cout << "Recieve thread started" << endl;
}
```

But the compiler gives this error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Eigenaar\Bureaublad\BluetoothTestr\test\main.cpp||In function `int main()':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Eigenaar\Bureaublad\BluetoothTestr\test\main.cpp|39|error: invalid conversion from `void (*)(void*)' to `DWORD (*)(void*)'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Eigenaar\Bureaublad\BluetoothTestr\test\main.cpp|39|error:   initializing argument 3 of `void* CreateThread(_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES*, DWORD, DWORD (*)(void*), void*, DWORD, DWORD*)'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Eigenaar\Bureaublad\BluetoothTestr\test\recievethread.h|4|warning: 'void recieveFunct(void*)' declared `static' but never defined|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I'm getting the error when I call the `CreateThread` function.

Comment: You would probably be better off using a threading library than doing this directly, eg. Boost.Thread, docs at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html.  Thread management has a bunch of complexities that you don't want to handle over and over in your own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `nxt` to `LPVOID`, not `HANDLE`. MSDN says "`LPVOID lpParameter` [in, optional] - A pointer to a variable to be passed to the thread." This design pattern for passing data to a callback function or thread is commonly called a "user data" pointer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can just cast your Brick pointer to `LPVOID` (i.e. a pointer to void) when you call `CreateThread()` and uncast it in your `recieveFunct` thread func:

```
static void recieveFunct(void* pvBrick)
{
    Brick* brick = reinterpret_cast<Brick*>(pvBrick);
}

Connection *connection = new Bluetooth(); Brick *nxt = new Brick(connection);
IDRecieveThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, recieveFunct, reinterpret_cast<void*>(nxt), 0, NULL);
```

Also, you might consider using `beginthreadex()` instead of `CreateThread()` if you are using the MSVCRT library. `beginthreadex()` will ensure that MSVCRT is properly initialized for your thread.

Comment: beginthreadex has not been required to make sure that the CRT is initialised for many, many versions. Otherwise, the CRT wouldn't work on thread pool threads.

even the crt _endthreadex is not required unless you are static linking the CRT and have disabled thread library calls.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx gives "A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread; this requires the use of the multi-threaded version of the CRT. If a thread created using CreateThread calls the CRT, the CRT may terminate the process in low-memory conditions."

Comment: @cdarke That is clearly out of date and refers to an old CRT. You can tell that from the mention of the long forgotten separate single- and multi-threaded versions of the CRT.

Answer (score 3):

Use this signature:

```
DWORD WINAPI recieveFunct(void* pParam)
{
   Brick* pBrick = (Brick*)pParam; // Or whichever casting you prefer

  // Use the  `pBrick`

  return 0;
}
```

Create the thread as:

```
Brick *nxt = new Brick(connection);
CreateThread(NULL, 0, recieveFunct, (void*)nxt, 0, NULL);
```